# I am having trouble getting passEntered and userEntered into another class

Tags: java, string, class

I am having a problem getting variables from one class to another **(passEntered and userEntered)** the are giving errors every time I set them up. I have tried getters and setters but it doesn't seem to work. The variables are getting inputs but don't seem to want to share to other classes.

First Class:

```
public class LoginGUI {
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel ("Enter Your Password:");
    private JButton loginButton = new JButton ("Login");
    **JTextArea usernameEnter = new JTextArea (0, 0);**
    private JLabel usernameLabel = new JLabel ("Enter Your Username:");
    **JPasswordField passwordEnter = new JPasswordField (5);**
    private JLabel registerLabel = new JLabel ("If you dont have an account register here:");
    private JButton registerButton = new JButton ("Register");
    **public String userEntered;
    public String passEntered;**

    public LoginGUI() {
        PanelSetup();
        FrameSetup();
        setBounds();

        loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                **userEntered = usernameEnter.getText();
                passEntered = passwordEnter.getText();**
                System.out.println(passEntered);
                System.out.println(userEntered);

            }

        });

        registerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource()==registerButton){
                    frame.dispose();
                    registerGUI myWindow = new registerGUI();
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Second Class:

```
public class loginChecker {
String username, password;

    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new loginChecker();
    }

    private void loginChecker() {
        setUsername();
        setPassword();
    }

    private void setPassword() {
        password = passEntered;
    }

    private void setUsername() {
        username = userEntered;
    }

}
```

If you could help it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I had tried to make getters/setters before they didn't work so in this instance I made userEntered and passEntered (whats entered in the GUI) public to be seen by other classes. When I tried to set return values it gave me all types of errors. userEntered and passEntered are supposed to be changed to username and password in loginChecker but username and password variables never show up

Comment: Oh and also there is mention of loginChecker I had to remove it because stackoverflow closed my previous question because it was to long

Answer (score 1):

The class `loginChecker` should start with an uppercase letter, as the naming conventions suggest. Other than that, how should the class know the `passEntered` and `userEntered` variables? I would change the class like so:

```
public class LoginChecker {
    public String username, password;
    public void changePassword(String newPassword) {
        // TODO: Check whether the password matches some criteria
        // TODO: Encrypt password
        password=newPassword;
    }
    public void changeUsername(String newUsername) {
        // TODO: Check Username availability
        username = newUsername;
    }
    public String getUsername() { return username; }
    // Could also change the signature to use a key String that will be used to decrypt an encrypted password
    public String getPassword() { return password; }
}
```

*Also, you should probably not store passwords unencrypted.*
Inside the `LoginGUI` class, you save a reference to a `LoginChecker` object and use its fields.

```
...
LoginChecker loginChecker = new LoginChecker();
...
loginChecker.changeUsername(usernameEnter.getText());
loginChecker.changePassword(passwordEnter.getText());
// You can then get the password and username using loginChecker.getUsername() and loginChecker.getPassword()
```

Comment: You don't realize how much this has helped. Thanks for the advice on encrypting too (although I don't know what you mean).

Comment: @AstroCool I know this wasn't the original question and the topic of cryptography is *really* deep (and advanced), so I am just going to give you a link to an explanation; about halfway through they start with String encryption/decryption. https://www.baeldung.com/java-aes-encryption-decryption

Comment: wow thats a lot I might have to watch a youtube video to really learn how to use encryptions for passwords and such. Thanks for letting me know